# How can I find everything until something else in PHP and return that as a string?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, preg-replace, seo

I want to return these unique values from my URLs

```
394_black
500_mono2
```

The URLs:

```
/shop/swarovski/394_black_the-reagan-swarovski-maxi-dress
/shop/celeb/500_mono2_the-reagan-swarovski-maxi-dress
```

Can I do this in PHP?

Pseudo Code

```
$url    =       get url
$firstvar = after 3rd / and after second _ save text (500_mono2) from $url

$secondvar = using $firstvar return only first 3 numbers
//substr($firstvar, 0, 3);  (I think this will be it)
```

## Updated my Question above, easier to understand

Comment: Strictly speaking, those aren't urls... they're just paths. If you're starting with a full-blown http://... url, the use parse_str to break it into parts, then use standard path manipulation stuff (basename, etc...) to split up the path.

Comment: Since you are using URL rewriting, I don't understand why you need to do that in PHP. This is automatically done by the rewriting rules you put in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I have already done the rule in NGINX - which does not use .htaccess - on my PHP page I want to grab those values for my page to render. @Jocelyn

Comment: Can you show us the rewriting rules?

Comment: @Jocelyn why do you need to see them?

Comment: When properly written, rewriting rules will put in the query string the values you need. Then you just have to retrieve the values stored in $_GET, there is no need to write PHP code to parse the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $url = '/shop/celeb/500_mono2_the-reagan-swarovski-maxi-dress';
    $urlparts = explode('/', $url);

    list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode('_', end($urlparts));

    echo $var1 . '<br>' . $var2 . '<br>' . $var3;

?>
```

Comment: I like answers like this. No questions, no explanations - nada. Just the solution. +1